# create attributes from positional arguments in python

Tags: python, attributes

I have a member function that I pass parameters into which refer to different python objects

```
foo(model, data)
```

foo is defined as

```
def foo(self, *args):
    ...
```

How can I define this function so as to use setattr to dynamically set attributes of the respective class. What I want to end up with for this specific case are two class attributes called model and data which point to the respective objects. In other words, how can I use the args tuple in conjunction with setattr to set attributes of the respective name?

Answer (score 0):

Help for `setattr`:

> setattr(obj, name, value, /)
>       Sets the named attribute on the given object to the specified value.
>
> ```
> setattr(x, 'y', v) is equivalent to x.y = v
> ```

As you are defining the function, you want to use **args not *args. That gives you a dict not a tuple.

Then you can make a call like

```
foo(model=model, data=data)
```

And in your defined function:

```
for key in args:
    setattr(self, key, args[key])
```

Otherwise with a tuple there is no way to get to a name for each arg, you have to know the names apriori, because you access by index.